# Input reset button bug on input size CSS

Tags: html, css

I don't know exactly how to describe it but I have a problem that if I click on the input and so the autcomplete appears below and the problem is that it changes the input and I don't know why I mainly think it's a problem in css looking here 4 Days but I didn't come to that's why i need advice i am sending my code and also javascript if it is somehow needed. if any information is needed just write in the comment

CSS:

```css
#icon{
    display: none;
}

#icon.active{
    display: flex;
}
```

Autocomplete box CSS :

```css
#search-button{
    all: unset;
}
body:not(:focus-within) #autocomplete, #autocomplete:not(.not-empty) {
    display: none;
}
#autocomplete {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 24vw;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    bottom: 290px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    min-width: 480px;
    max-width: 480px;

    transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
    --animation-duration: 200ms;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);

}

#autocomplete a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    padding: .2rem .5rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
#autocomplete a:hover, #autocomplete a:focus, #autocomplete a:active {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 3px;
    transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
    --animation-duration: 200ms;
}
#autocomplete .nobold {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#autocomplete {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

JS :

```js
const input = document.getElementById("search-input");
const button = document.getElementById("cancel")
const icon = document.getElementById("icon");

input.addEventListener('keyup', changeIconDisplay);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = '';
  changeIconDisplay();
});

function changeIconDisplay() {
  if (input.value.trim() == "" ) {
    icon.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    icon.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
```

** I have answer but not working very good**

```css
min-width: 480px;
```

you add this **min-width** is fix the position of icon but look is broke position of autocomplete box

[image: Bug of Box]

VIDEO :
https://i.imgur.com/Y2A355g.gif

if you need full code here is links:

view-source:https://heexy.org/style.css
view-source:https://heexy.org/

If something is unclear definitely write I understand that somewhere I could express myself wrong or inaccurately just ask thank you very much in advance.

> Translated by google translator

Comment: Need to see the HTML, but it seems to me that you need to add `position:relative` on the containing div

Comment: @Tristanisginger No, sorry is not help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please at first remove the CSS code "all: unset;"

```
/* Remove the CSS code - Start */
#search-button {
  all: unset;
}
/* Remove the CSS code - End */
```

Add all this CSS code. By using the code you will get a complete solution to your search layout problem.

```
/* Global Reset - Start */
button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  color: #8d8d8d;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.box > input {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
/* Global Reset - End */

/* Form Box - Start */
.box {
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  --animation-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
  -o-transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
  transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
}

.box > button {
  width: 55px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 55px;
  flex: 0 0 55px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 52px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #101010 !important;
}
/* Form Box - End */

/* Auto Complete - Start */
#autocomplete {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  --animation-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
  -o-transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
  transition: all var(--animation-duration) ease;
}
/* Auto Complete - End */
```

And also use this Js code. Here I just removed "flex" and added "inline-block"

```
const input = document.getElementById("search-input");
const button = document.getElementById("cancel")
const icon = document.getElementById("icon");

input.addEventListener('keyup', changeIconDisplay);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = '';
  changeIconDisplay();
});

function changeIconDisplay() {
  if (input.value.trim() == "" ) {
    icon.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    icon.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}
```

Comment: It will solve my problem but I would like to keep the original design which is that there is a gap which you deisgn has not made here a bit of my own version and I also did not do very well but if yb could be done so that my original design just stayed I would just like to modify it button "X" nothing else would it work? then it would solve my whole problem otherwise the code is great 99% My problem is solved I just have the design I had originally would it work?

Comment: Okay please only one thing help me make how can i change the size look on the image i need make the input start next to icon https://imgur.com/a/c1kt6FG

Comment: **@Whatery1010**
I think you wanted to decrease the space between the icon & input.
See the screenshot - [https://prnt.sc/mref5N6IrDSY].

Then add some space into the Left & Right sides of the Box to looks nice
See the screenshot - [https://prnt.sc/_ejjclEU1Zgu]

I hope it will help you.
Thank You.

Comment: Thank you, for help but we are have Answer ;) but really thank you

Answer (score 3):

I hope I can help.

try to change the position to absolute and set the position using top/bottom/left/right it should put the X in place.